# dynamically-generated inputs not working

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to make a dynamic table using jquery and html. Basically what it does is, from the text of an input it appends a new row with the text n one cell and a remove button in another cell. But my problem is that the click event of the input is not firing. Here are the scripts of adding and removing the rows

```
//Remove Row    
$('.remove-row').click(function () {
    alert('Works!');
});

//Add Row
$('.add-other-sources').click(function () {
    var $text=$(this).parent().parent().find('.other-sources-input');
    var $table=$(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.other-sources-table')
    $('<tr><td>'+$text.val()+'</td><td><input type="button" class="remove-row" value="x"/></td></tr>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo($table);
    $text.val("");
});
```

From what I could figure out on the web inspector, the tag of the input is showing up like this `<input type="button" class="remove-row" value="x">`. Does it has anything to do with the fact that the remove row event is not working?

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a delegated event handler:

```
//Remove Row    
$('table').on("click", ".remove-row", function () {
    alert('Works!');
});
```

The reason is that the normal handler is only attached to already existing elements. With the delegated handler the click is attached to a parent element, but the function is only executed if the source bubbled up from the selector you specified.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to  delegate the events** if you want to attach events to dynamically created elements.

```
$(staticContainer).on('click', '.remove-row',function () {
```

StatucContainer can be any container that is always present in the HTML. The closer to the elements in question , better the performance.